# Is it possible to select the same part of an image as a filler in each vector in a canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I hae an array of triangles that i draw like this, I'm trying to create a kaleidoscope-like pattern, so I would like to use the same portion of the image in each triangle. When I apply a pattern like this, the triangle works more like a cropping mask, exposing all of the image instead.

```
draw = () => {
        triangles.forEach((t) => {
            const pattern = c.createPattern(image, 'no-repeat')
            c.beginPath();
            c.moveTo(t.center.x, t.center.y)
            c.lineTo(t.right.x, t.right.y)
            c.lineTo(t.left.x, t.left.y)
            c.fillStyle = pattern
            c.fill();

        })

    }
fill()
image.src = 'http://www.allers.se/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/kungen-ny-700x525.jpg'
image.onload = function() {
  draw()
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cagpum6z/

Comment: The canvas can draw to itself. `ctx.drawImage(ctx.canvas,1,1)` If you want a shape you can draw the part of the canvas you want to an offscreen canvas that has a clip (or use a composite operation to mask) to get only an irregular part, then draw the offscreen canvas back to the display one. THe canvas is an image and you can do anything with it that you can do with an image and more.

Comment: If the original image gets updated, will the redrawn images get updated aswell?

Comment: No you will need to make a new copy each frame. But the canvas is quick and you can redraw the canvas many times and still have the animation run at 60fps